# OS X Shell Script Silent Mode

Tags: macos, shell, command, silent

I made a script that runs whenever the lid of my Macbook is opened. I'd like to be able to track my computer if I ever lost it or it was stolen. My problem is when it runs the locateme command, a window pops up and says "do you want to allow command 'locateme'?" The locateme command does not have any parameter for this (such as -v or -q).

How do I make the default answer to allow? Or how do I make the command run silently? I'm still a bit of a noob, so an explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")

# Grab picture and assign date as filename
imagesnap "/Users/Tim/Scripts/Logs/wakeup/$DATE.jpg"

# get the location
LAT=$(locateme -f {LAT})
LONG=$(locateme -f {LON})

# Get my external IP address
MYIP="$(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain)"

# Get current network name
NN=$(networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -c 24-)

#Create the txt file
cat <<EOF >/Users/Tim/Scripts/Logs/info/$DATE.txt
IP: $MYIP
Network: $NN
Google Maps Link:  https://maps.google.com/maps?q=$LAT,$LONG
EOF

# Synchronize everything on the Macbook to Dropbox
rsync -a ~/Scripts/Logs/wakeup ~/Dropbox/Logs
rsync -a ~/Scripts/Logs/info ~/Dropbox/Logs
```

EDIT: After some searching I found out that a process normally has two outputs to screen: stdout (standard out), and stderr (standard error). And you can turn them both off with this: mycommand 2>&1 >/dev/null

Unfortunately this didn't work. I thought it did, but apparently it just suppressed the command from running.

EDIT #2: I've also checked my security settings and found this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StiAE.jpg

I would like some advice on these settings, since the problem seems to be sort of random I can't be sure if this is what could be causing it.

Final EDIT:
Very late update, but it is working now. For anyone wondering, I needed to change my security settings in the System Preferences.

Comment: Does your machine have GPS? Otherwise all it can do is attempt to locate through visible WiFi signals. You might be better off just sending a signal "I am at IP address xxx" perhaps with the traceroute to a known server (so you can find out the IP address of whatever router / firewall it sits behind). I don't know that you can turn off the "permission on location" feature.  Really interesting attempt to create your own LoJack function!

Comment: This would presumably be specific to the `locateme` command, rather than a general "silent mode". It also sounds like that's a security prompt, so it may be deliberately difficult to avoid it.

Comment: see also: http://preyproject.com/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately my computer doesn't have gps. And yes I could send my IP address, but it is a big security risk if my email or dropbox were ever compromised.

Comment: @Tim, Are you more interested in running shell scripts silently or is it more a matter of the wanting specifically the Location Services acting silently?

Comment: Both would be a suitable solution. But yes, specifically in this case I am randomly getting a message from "locateme" asking if I want to allow it. It doesn't always happen though, I just restarted my computer and it hasn't asked me yet even though I've run the script multiple times.